# Is there a way to debug cscope?

Tags: linux, cscope

I'm trying to build a cscope code database (running `cscope -Rb`) on a reasonably-sized (not huge) codebase.

However, cscope is not returning. `htop` reports that cscope is using 100% of one CPU.

Over the past few months that I've been using it, cscope has completed creating the database (with previous iterations of the same codebase) in *maybe* as long as a minute.

I assume there's a bad code file somewhere that is causing the problem, but how do I determine which one it is if cscope just puts itself into what seems to be an infinite loop?

Comment: Try running `strace` on it and see if it's stuck or spinning somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for the idea; that probably would have worked. In the meantime, I've cleaned up my repository and am no longer having the problem.

Comment: I am having the same problem here.. Would you mind tell how did you solve this? and What clean up steps you have taken?

Comment: I believe I ran `git clean` (probably with some flags to protect untracked files etc) so that I had a clean repository with no object files or any other detritus of the build process. It's possible that I even created a new build directory with a clean repository and started from there. I'm sorry that I don't recall better.